# How to find a upper bound of the set $A= \{ (1+\frac{1}{n})^n : n \in \mathbb{N}^{*} \} $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, real-numbers

i have the set $A= \{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n} : n \in \mathbb{N}^* \}$ and the exercise ask me to find at least $2$ upper bound least equal to $\frac{14}{5}$.

My first question is, how i know $\frac{14}{5}$ is a upper bound of $A$?

My attempt is show doesn't exist $m \in \mathbb{N}^*$ such that $(1+\frac{1}{m})^{m} = \frac{14}{5}$, but i'm stuck,  for the other upper bound numbers, i could reason the same way?

Thanks for suggestions

Comment: Hint: what can you say about $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$? This limit should look familiar.

Comment: Also note $14/5=2.8$. Finally, check that the sequence $a_n:=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ is increasing, so it is bounded above by its limit.

Comment: @Michael Morrow the intended way was probably to bound the series expansion directly in some way. (Now addressing the OP) You could use the fact that $n!$ grows faster than $k^n$, and use this to bound small terms by a geometric series.

Comment: An upper bound of $3$ can be found very easily, see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334832/prove-limit-converges-in-definition-of-e). $14/5$ will probably be more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not allowed to use the definition of $e$, then by observing that the sequence terms are bound by (refer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1334832/prove-limit-converges-in-definition-of-e))
$$
\begin{align}\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac 1n\right)^k\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}\left(\frac 1n\right)^k\\&=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\left(1-\frac 1n\right)\left(1-\frac 2n\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{k-1}{n}\right)\\&\lt \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\\
&=1+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{4\cdot 3\cdot 2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n\cdot(n-1)\cdots 2}\\
&\lt 1+\frac{1}{2^0}+\frac{1}{2^1}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\\&=3-\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\\&\lt 3\end{align}
$$
Now to get a stricter bound, since
$$
\frac{1}{2^1} + \frac{1}{3\cdot 2}+\frac{1}{4\cdot 3\cdot 2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n\cdot(n-1)\cdots 2} < \frac
{1}{2} \left( 1+\frac{1}{2^0}+\frac{1}{3^1}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3^{n-1}} \right)
$$
we have
$$
\left(1+\frac 1n\right)^n < 1 + \frac{1}{2^0} + \frac
{1}{2} \left(\frac{1}{3^0}+\frac{1}{3^1}+\frac{1}{3^2}+\frac{1}{3^3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{3^{n-1}} \right) < 2 + \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{3}} = \frac{11}{4} < \frac{14}{5}
$$
as required.

Answer (score 0):

First you should know that:
$$ (1) \ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+O(x^3)$$
Also consider that ln is an injective function meaning if $\ln(A)=1$ then $A=e$ 
So:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \ln(A) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \ln((1+\frac{1}{n})^n = \lim_{n\to\infty} n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) $$
Applying (1):
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} n\ln(1+\frac{1}{n}) = \lim_{n\to\infty} n(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+O(\frac{1}{n^3}))$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} n(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{2n^2}+O(\frac{1}{n^3})) = \lim_{n\to\infty} (1-\frac{1}{2n}+nO(\frac{1}{n^3})) = 1 $$
Since $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \ln(A) = 1 $$ Than $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} A = e $$
So e is the least upper bound and any number greater than e is an upper bound (Note: $\frac{14}{5} > e $)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the upper bound of this sequence is the standard definition of $e$. More formally,
$$
e=\lim_{n\to\infty} (1+{1\over n})^n\approx 2.71828182846
$$
To reject $14\over 5$ as an upper bound, note that $e< 14/5$.

Comment: I believe they are required to prove this w/o using $e$.