# Prove $e=\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}(1+\frac1x)^x$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

The same exercise requires us to prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty}x\log(1+\frac1x)=1$ just before proving the identity in the title. I can use this fact as follows:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(1+\frac1x\right)^x=\lim_{x \to \infty}e^{x\log(1+\frac1x)}=e$$

Is this proof valid? I'm asking because the author is using a complicated $\varepsilon-\delta$ proof which could have been avoided, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: This depends on what you are allowed to use. Yet, this proof would be fine.

Comment: They have not disallowed to use the identity $a^x=e^{x\log{a}}$

Comment: Ok, then it is fine.

Comment: You do need to show that you can move the limit to the exponent. That requires showing that exponentiation is continuous. But yeah, your proof is good.

Comment: @Eric now I see that it was the point of the $\delta-\varepsilon$ proof.

Comment: Here's my fave https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4074292/403337

Answer (score -1):

If you have
$\log(1+x)
=\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+t}
$,
then,
if $x > 0$,
$\log(1+x)
=\int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+t}
\lt\int_0^x dt
=x$
and
$\log(1+x)
\gt \int_0^x \dfrac{dt}{1+x}
= \dfrac{x}{1+x}
= \dfrac{x+x^2-x^2}{1+x}
= x-\dfrac{x^2}{1+x}
$
so
$0
\gt \dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x}-1
\gt -\dfrac{x}{1+x}
$
so
$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\log(1+x)}{x}
=1
$.

This is probably your proof.